# how to reset my score (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, reset

I have the following code in my javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#shuffle, #game_over_shuffle").bind("click", shuffleBoard);
});
```

This shuffles some things in a div. Now I also have a scoring system that looks like this:

```
// Ad score
var score = 0;
```

You can use a hint, but that will reduce your score (cut from a bigger function):

```
// Remove 500 points when used
    score -= 500;
      $('#score').text(score);
```

This all works, but now I want to reset the score to 0 when the suffle is used. I've tried this:

```
$("#shuffle, #game_over_shuffle").bind("click", shuffleBoard, resetScore);
```

Note I've added resetScore and made a new function to reset the score:

```
function resetScore(){
    score = 0;
      $('#score').text(score);
};
```

But this doesn't reset the score to 0. What am I missing?

Kind regards,
Maurice

================================

Found a solution myself. Instead of creating a new function, I extended an existing one (using the same bind) setting the score to 0. Thanks to all trying to help me!

Comment: That's not enough information for us to help really, sorry. When you it doesn't what do you see? Nothing? Something else? An error in your browser's javascript console? Are you sure resetScore is actually getting called - if you throw an alert() in there does it get hit? etc. Anything else you can possibly tell us will helP!

Comment: Does `bind` accept an arbitary number of functions? I've never used it, or seen it, like that--are you sure `resetScore` is actually being called?

Comment: Could you tell us what `shuffleboard` does? I think the `resetScore()`-function is never called. Try changing the click-handler to `.bind('click', resetScore);`

Comment: Hi all, edited the code a bit to show some more info, also with a link to the entire code (since it is too big to past it in here). THe idea is the reset the score when clicking the shuffle link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution myself. Instead of creating a new function, I extended an existing one (using the same bind) setting the score to 0. Thanks to all trying to help me!

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass one event handler to the `bind` method. You'll have to call those two functions from within an anonymous function:

```
$("#shuffle, #game_over_shuffle").bind("click", function() {
    shuffleBoard();
    resetScore();
});
```

Here's a live example with this code:
http://jsbin.com/iresem/edit

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but it doesn't seem to work: 
`$(document).ready(function(){
$("#shuffle, #game_over_shuffle").bind("click", function() {
    shuffleBoard();
    resetScore();
});
});
function resetScore(){
 score = 0;
   $('#score').text(score);
};`
Result is no reset

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery 1.5 then you can leverage the new [Deferred Objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

Something like this:

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();
deferred.done(shuffleBoard).done(resetScore);

$("#shuffle, #game_over_shuffle").bind("click", function() {
    deferred.resolve();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, tried your code but no luck, think I put the var at a wrong place cause the application aint working at all when implementing this.